# Works on local machine but throws: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\JobsController] does not exist. on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have just hosted my Laravel application on Heroku but the strange thing is that the app is working fine on the local machine but on Heroku, include files are not working and when I try to access some routes which are working fine on my windows machine, it throws an error:

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\JobsController] does not exist.
```

Please check this URL: https://skillhunt.herokuapp.com/jobs and https://skillhunt.herokuapp.com/jobs/create
Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: The case sensitivity of the filename and class name and namespace are matching in the controller that should be `JobsController` ?

Comment: Thank you! @lagbox just checked out and found out that I had recreated the JobsController but instead of using capital J I used small j. So I really don't know why it is working on windows. After making the changes from ```jobsController``` to ```JobsController``` and committing, it is now working.